# XPath: Selecting from a nodeset returned from a function

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm just starting out with XSLT, so bear with me. I am processing a fairly complex document with a structure similar to the one below. It is divided into two sections, `data` and `meta`. For each `data/item` I need to look up the "actual" class in the corresponding `meta/item`.

```
<root>
  <data>
    <item id="i1">
      <h3 id="p2">akkakk</h3>
      <p id="p3">osijaoid</p>
      <p id="p4">jqidqjwd</p>
    <item>
  </data>
  <meta>
    <item ref="i1">
      <p ref="p2" class="heading"/>
      <p ref="p3" class="heading"/>
      <p ref="p4" class="body"/>
    </item>
  </meta>
</root>
```

I need to group adjacent `p` elements in `meta` on their class attribute. I thought a helper function could make this a bit cleaner:

```
<xsl:function name="fn:node-groups" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="parent"/>
  <xsl:variable name="nodeRefs" select="root($parent)//meta/item[@ref = $parent/@id]/p"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodeRefs" group-adjacent="@class">
    <group class="{@class}">
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <node ref="{@ref}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:function>
```

And then use it when processing the data nodes, like so. My problem is that I can not select further from the nodeset returned by the function.

```
<xsl:template match="//data/item">
  <!-- works -->
  <xsl:variable name="test1" select="fn:node-groups(.)"/>
  <!-- works -->
  <xsl:variable name="test2" select="fn:node-groups(.)/*"/>
  <!-- does not work -->
  <xsl:variable name="test3" select="fn:node-groups(.)/group[@class = 'heading']"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I *can* write a star as in `test2`, and that gives me all `node` nodes. But anything else just gives me an empty nodeset. Or at least it looks that way, but at this point I really don't know anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your stylesheet has an `xmlns="http://example.com/foo"` namespace declaration scope for the function that puts the result elements in the function in that namespace and then obviously `fn:node-groups(.)/group` will not select them as it selects a `group` element in no namespace. So make sure your function overrides that namespace with `<xsl:for-each-group select="$nodeRefs" group-adjacent="@class" xmlns="">`.

Another reason could be that your stylesheet defines `xpath-default-namespace`.

I also think that your third variable needs to be `<xsl:variable name="test3" select="mf:node-groups(.)/node"/>` as obviously the node sequence returned by your function already is a sequence of `group` elements, if you want to filter that sequence then use `<xsl:variable name="test3" select="fn:node-groups(.)[@class = 'heading']"/>`

Comment: Thank you! The problem was as of course that I needed to select `fn:node-groups(.)/[@class = 'heading']` instead of `fn:node-groups(.)/group[@class = 'heading']`. Sometimes you get stuck and need a nudge in the right direction to be able to go on.